# Выполнение шорткода при нажатии на картинку

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт на движке вордпресс, установлен плагин ninja popups
В коде страницы прописано следующее:

```html
<div style= "position:fixed; right:0px; bottom:55%;">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ninja-popup ID=700] тут должна быть картинка [/ninja-popup]'); ?>
  </div>
```

Как вставить картинку между тегами шорткода? 
Побывал так :

```html
<?php 

   $a = "<img src='http://xn--d1alcggabcc5a.xn--p1ai/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/199.png'>"; 


?> 
<div style= "position:fixed; right:0px; bottom:55%;">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ninja-popup ID=700] echo $a [/ninja-popup]'); ?>
  </div>
```

Но без результатов, даже обычный код для вставки изображения не работает в тегах шорткода.

Comment: Можно закрывать, решил проблему.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $a = "<img src='http://xn--d1alcggabcc5a.xn--p1ai/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/199.png'>";
?> 
<div style= "position:fixed; right:0px; bottom:55%;">
   <?=do_shortcode('[ninja-popup ID=700]'.$a.'[/ninja-popup]')?>
</div>
```

для склеивания переменной со строкой выносите её за пределы кавычки соединяя строку и переменную точкой